# BigCommerce API v2 Product Add with SKU

Tags: api, bigcommerce

We are trying to implement the v2 API in BigCommerce to be able to add products to BigCommerce from our system.

It seems that you cannot set the Product SKU field when adding a product. This makes the product API totally meaningless. Is this by design?

How are we supposed to know if a product is already added if it does not have a SKU? SKU should be updateable for ADD product case, it can be ready only for UPDATE product case. I think this is a serious bug in the API.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products#create-product

Please advise how to add product with API with SKU.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the API documentation for the SKU resource under Create Product,  https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/skus#create-product-sku, you will see that you first have to add the base SKU or the parent and then the options, or Skus. The call to add the Sku must contain the parent product ID, `POST /api/v2/products/{product_id}/skus`. You cannot do it in one API call to my knowledge